# Is there a datastore viewer in google app engine launcher?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a datastore viewer in Google App Engine Launcher? Something similar to the Datastore Viewer that can be found within the GAE website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a datastore viewer that is specifically part of the Launcher, but the dev server provides an admin console that has a datastore viewer. While dev_appserver.py (or whatever the Java equivalent is) is running, go to /_ah/admin in your browser.

Comment: Thanks, only one comment though: that server is at /_ah/admin

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Click on 'SDK console' when your app is running; this is the equivalent to going to /_ah/admin as suggested by Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Under Eclipse there is plugin: http://appwrench.onpositive.com/index.page